# Discrete Math-Computing Summations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

So I'm asked to compute a summation with an upper limit $k = 20$ and lower limit $k=1$, where:

$B_k= 0$ when $k=1$, 
and
$B_k = \dfrac{1}{(k^2-1)}$ ,  for $k>1$.

I was wondering if there is a quicker way than adding all $20$ terms because the only way I know is computing each term individually and adding them up to the upper limit. But in this case, it's just too much.

Thanks,
L

Answer (score 0):

$2S = 2B_2 + 2B_3 + \cdots + 2B_{20}$

$2B_k = \dfrac{2}{k^2-1} = \dfrac{1}{k-1} - \dfrac{1}{k+1}= \left(\dfrac{1}{k-1} - \dfrac{1}{k}\right) + \left(\dfrac{1}{k} - \dfrac{1}{k+1}\right)$.

When you add the terms it will telescope twice. Can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you start adding these twenty terms, and if you do so, you might notice a pattern. Unless it's too much work of course.

$B_2 = 1/3$, $B_3 = 1/8$, $B_4 = 1/15$, $B_5 = 1/24$, $B_6 = 1/35$, $B_7 = 1/48$, $B_8 = 1/63$, $B_9 = 1/80$, $B_10 = 1/99$, $B_11 = 1/120$, ... It looks easier to add every second term.

$1/3 + 1/15 = 6/15 = 2/5$.

$2/5 + 1/35 = 14/35 + 1/35 = 15/35 = 3/7$.

$3/7 + 1/63 = 27/63 + 1/63 = 28/63 = 4/9$.

$4/9 + 1/99 = 44/99 + 1/99 = 45/99 = 5/11$. I hope you see the pattern.

$1/8 + 1/24 = 3/24 + 1/24 = 4/24 = 1/6 (= 2/12)$.

$1/6 + 1/48 = 8/48 + 1/48 = 9/48 = 3/16$

$3/16 + 1/80 = 15/80 + 1/80 = 16/80 = 1/5 (= 4/20)$.

$1/5 + 1/120 = 24/120 + 1/120 = 25/120 = 5/24$. I hope you see that pattern as well. So now you should be able to write down a formula and prove it using complete induction.